# Почему вызов метода у Com объекта бросает исключение

Tags: c#, .net, com

Как известно, что бы узнать кол-во доступных видео адаптеров через интерфейс `DXGI`, необходимо вызывать метод `EnumAdapters` до тех пор, пока данный метод не вернет значение `DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND`.

Казалось бы, будет перечислять через цикл `while`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int result = Manager.CreateDxgiFactory(out IDXGIFactory factory);

        if (result != 0)
        {
            Exception erForHr = Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(result);
            throw erForHr;
        }

        uint count = 0;
        while (factory.EnumAdapters(count, out _) == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
        ...
    }
```

Но не тут то было! Как только значение `count` станет больше чем доступно адаптеров, получаем исключение...

> Объект не найден. При вызове IDXGIFactory::EnumAdaptes отсутствует
>   адаптер с указанным порядковым номером. (Исключение из HRESULT:
>   0x887A0002)

Почему, и как платформа `.NET` обнаруживает то что произошло исключение, если в коде самостоятельно нигде не бросается исключение?

Как отключить данный функционал, т.к. надо перечислять пока есть доступные адаптеры?

Или необходимо оборачивать код в `try/catch` и в блоке `catch` выходить из цикла?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COM Interop по умолчанию преобразует все неуспешные возвращенные HRESULT в исключения. Добавьте атрибут [PreserveSig](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.preservesigattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2), чтобы это предотвратить:

```
[PreserveSig] int EnumAdapters(...);
```